# How to make users send mails with it's SMTP in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make users send emails with it's own SMTP Data in laravel

i tried to set the new env variables of SMTP like this

```
env('MAIL_USERNAME', $smtp->smtp_username);
```

and tried this also

```
config(['MAIL_USERNAME' => $smtp->smtp_username]);
```

and nothing updated

then tried to set the SMTP data in mail.php

but i got errors while deploying

Comment: PHP cannot be put in an env file. What is `$smtp` and how is it declared? What errors?

Answer (score 3):

This works at least in laravel 8+ and not overide default mailer nor config (so no problem with cache)

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;
use Swift_Mailer;
use Swift_SmtpTransport;

class CustomMailer
{
    
    private array $config;
    
    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }
    
    public function make(): Mailer
    {
        $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport($this->getConfigValue('host'), $this->getConfigValue('port')))
            ->setEncryption($this->getConfigValue('encryption'))
            ->setUsername($this->getConfigValue('username'))
            ->setPassword($this->getConfigValue('password'));
        
        $mailer = new Mailer(
            'customMailer',
            app()->get('view'),
            new Swift_Mailer($transport),
            app()->get('events')
        );
        
        $mailer->alwaysFrom(
            $this->getConfigValue('from_email', $this->getConfigValue('username')),
            $this->getConfigValue('from_name', $this->getConfigValue('username')),
        );
        
        return $mailer;
    }
    
    private function getConfigValue(string $key, mixed $default = null): mixed
    {
        return data_get($this->config, $key, $default);
    }
}
```

#Usage

```
(new CustomMailer([
            'host'       => '****',
            'port'       => 465,
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
            'username'   => '****',
            'password'   => '****',
        ]))
            ->make()
            ->to('****@***.**')
            ->send(new someEmail());
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
// backup mailing configuration
        $backup = Mail::getSwiftMailer();

        // set mailing configuration
        $transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport(
                                    getUserActiveEmailDetails()->host, 
                                    getUserActiveEmailDetails()->port, 
                                    getUserActiveEmailDetails()->encryption
                                );

        $transport->setUsername(getUserActiveEmailDetails()->username);
        $transport->setPassword(getUserActiveEmailDetails()->password);

        $maildoll = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

        // set mailtrap mailer
        Mail::setSwiftMailer($maildoll);

        Mail::send('testing.mail', [], function($message)
        {
            $message->from(getUserActiveEmailDetails()->from)
                    ->to(org('test_connection_email'), 
                     Str::ucfirst(activeEmailService()) . ' Test Connection')
                    ->subject(Str::ucfirst(activeEmailService()) . ' Test 
                     Connection');
                   });

        // reset to default configuration
        Mail::setSwiftMailer($backup);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely the wrong approach in my opinion. You can't set env or config dynamically and you would also overwrite it for every single user in the page. Also queuing mail is not possible that way..

Have a look at this:

https://laravel-news.com/allowing-users-to-send-email-with-their-own-smtp-settings-in-laravel

This seems like a pretty complete approach to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks dear ..
Is there any another way instead using Swift_Mailer ?

Comment: Well, laravel uses Swift_Mailer under the hood anyway. So that's why it might be a good choice. Of course you can also install any smtp package you like and use that.